# How to centralize navigation bar in bootstrap

Tags: css, navigation

What can i do to centralize navigation bar with a website like this.I tried `margin:0 auto;` in `.navigation` property in `style.css` but it hasn't changed a bit.
Website: http://theembazaar.com/demo/eforest/iconic/

Comment: Do you have any other code to show other than the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any of your code snippets, this is the simplest example (using Bootstrap).

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="nav justify-content-center">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </nav>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @kiavashkazerani Are you talking about vertically *and* horizontally centered on the page?

Comment: yes i want this ...i tried this code but nothing happens

Comment: Did you add these `<link>` and `<script>` tags in the proper places in the HTML page?

Comment: yes... can you review my website code? http://theembazaar.com/demo/eforest/iconic/ i will appreciate your help

Comment: It looks like you have a `float: right;` attached to the `ul` (`.header ul {...}`) in your CSS. If you remove that line of CSS, the text goes more towards center. However, you have the logo wrapped in a `.col-md-3` which pushes that navigation list over a bit.

Comment: it dosen't help... because when i delete .col-md-3 section in html page  and removing css float property all links came to left

Comment: So you have a few options depending on the result(s) you want. You can remove `.col-md-3` and the `float: right;`  and add `.justify-content-center` to the `row` (then add CSS to the logo for desired spacing). That will center the entire `nav`.